# System.Collections Vs System.Collections.ObjectModel

Tags: c#, .net, collections

There seem to be certain collection classes in System.Collections.ObjectModel as well. What is the difference between the collections under these two namespaces and in which scenario should we use System.Collections.ObjectModel?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.objectmodel.aspx):

> The System.Collections.ObjectModel
> namespace contains classes that can be
> used as collections in the object
> model of a reusable library. Use these
> classes when properties or methods
> return collections.

See also [The reason why Collection, ReadOnlyCollection, and KeyedCollection were moved to System.Collections.ObjectModel namespace](https://web.archive.org/web/20151030064839/http://blogs.msdn.com/b/kcwalina/archive/2005/03/15/396086.aspx)

Comment: plus one for the link to 'why' I just opened some code where the `System.Collections.ObjectModel.Collection` were being used and clearly they're not supposed to be used.

Comment: I know this is old but the link is outdated now and I was interested in the content. Found it on Internet Archive and sharing it https://web.archive.org/web/20151030064839/http://blogs.msdn.com/b/kcwalina/archive/2005/03/15/396086.aspx

Answer (score 1):

[`System.Collections.ObjectModel`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.objectmodel) classes are useful for exposing your collections to the outside world. (By outside world I mean code that does not version with your code.)

So use generic collection classes in your code, but wrap it in a [`Collection<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.objectmodel.collection-1), [`ReadOnlyCollection<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.objectmodel.readonlycollection-1), or [`ObservableCollection<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.objectmodel.observablecollection-1) when you want to expose it to the outside world.

To wrap a collection as a keyed collection, the [`KeyedCollection`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.objectmodel.keyedcollection-2) can be used as a base class for a helper.

Answer (score 0):

One obvious difference is that the [`System.Collections.ObjectModel`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.objectmodel) namespace contains generic
readonly collections (i.e. without the Add, Remove and Clear methods etc).